# Deleting a dynamically allocated object inside of an object inside of an array

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I have a destructor that looks like this:

```
Tilemap::~Tilemap(void)
{
    if(width>0 && height > 0)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < getMapWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < getMapHeight(); y++)
            {
                if(getTileAtPoint(x,y)->isInteractable())
                {
                    delete getTileAtPoint(x,y)->getInteractable();
                }
            }
        }

        SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(tileArray);
    }

    return;
}
```

SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY() is just a macro that looks like this:

```
#define SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(ptr) { if(ptr) { delete [](ptr); (ptr)=NULL; } }
```

The tileArray is a dynamically allocated array that contains tiles which contains interactable objects. Its declaration looks like this:

```
tileArray = new Tile[mapWidth*mapHeight];
```

Whenever I delete the double for-loop section of code and just leave this:

```
Tilemap::~Tilemap(void)
{
    if(width>0 && height > 0)
    {
        SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(tileArray);
    }
}
```

I get memory leaks because there is an interactable object that I declared that is not getting deleted. However, when I leave the double for-loops, the code makes it through the for-loops just fine but then crashes on the SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY with this error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x008927CC in Spaceship.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

Does anyone know a way to fix this please?

Comment: Debug your program and found out, we don't have enough information to do that. Use smart pointers and containers and the problem will solve itself. Also, you can delete null pointers; it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple pattern: have the destructor of your tile objects delete their Interactable objects if they have them. That way deleting a tile cleans up automatically and you don't have to worry about this on the outside.

Or use some type of smart pointer instead of a raw pointer for the objects referenced by your Tile class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just looked and my Tiles were already deleting the interactables so they were getting deleted twice. That was a lot of wasted time for such a simple problem. Thank you!

Comment: The two recommendations here (destructor v smart pointer) do very different things. The smart pointer will deallocate the parent object, but not any dynamically allocated memory belonging to said parent.  Also, if you are going to implement your own destructor you should follow the rule of three.